# How do I "force" passages I copy to my Word files to use up all the available line space?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010, pdf-reader

I like to copy noteworthy passages from PDF books to Word documents. Problem is that PDF "line width" or "line space" is narrower than the width of a Word document. Thus I get unreadable, unnecessary long passages in my word documents that read more like a poem than a paragraph.

Is there a way to re-format a paragraph in a word document to use all the space? Here is an example:

> word word word
>
> word word word
>
> word word word

I would like to read like:

> word word wordword word wordword word wordword word wordword word
>   wordword word wordword word wordword word wordword word wordword word
>   wordword word word

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the lines you want to merge.
2. Open the Replace dialog (click `CTRL+H`).
3. In the "Find what" field type `^p` to find paragraph end marks.
4. In the "Replace with" field type a single space, assuming you want to separate the last word of every paragraph from the first word of the next one. Your example shows some "wordword" examples, so if this was intentional don't type anything in the "Replace with" field.
5. Click "Replace All".

[image]